# Dynamically add ListView to Tabs in TabHost

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to dynamically add Tabs to a TabHost and add a ListView to each of those tabs. The problem is that I get the following error ***"Could not create tab content because could not find view with id XX"***. The thing is that I am giving an ID to each new ListView and adding the view to the TabHost.

```
TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();
TabSpec tspec;
 for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++){
ListView lview = new ListView(this);
lview.setId(c+5000);    
mTabHost.addView(lview);
lview.setAdapter(aa);
tspec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test" + String.valueOf(c)).setIndicator("TAB "+ String.valueOf(c)).setContent(lview.getId());
    mTabHost.addTab(tspec);
}
```

I also tried adding the new ListView to the TabWidget and the FrameLayout but the results are the same. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

It need a new Activity which is used to load ListView.

```
TabSpec moreSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec(“ListViewActivity”).setIndicator(“ListViewActivity”).setContent(new Intent(this,ListViewActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to refer the demo of Developer site. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Now, Add the subActivity to the tabActivity and in that listActivity implement the Listview to add listView dynamicaly.

Hope it will help you. If not then let me know.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: I followed that example before asking, but that's exactly what I want to avoid. What I really want is to do swap Views with in the same activity instead of using separate activities.